# Is there any good in-depth Ruby OOP materials?

Tags: ruby, oop

I want to know about object-oriented model in Ruby. And i want to go as deep as possible.
I'm looking for anything: video, article, book. Thanks.

Comment: It's a good thing to know this, but too general a question to answer in SO. Suggestion: Post some Ruby code that does something you don't fully understand, and ask a question about why it behaves a certain way.

Comment: Check out Dave Thomas's [Ruby Object Model](http://scotland-on-rails.s3.amazonaws.com/2A04_DaveThomas-SOR.mp4) talk, and Sandi Metz's book [Practical Object-oriented Design in Ruby](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321721330)

Comment: I liked [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476). The first part of the book contains very nice explanation of object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`The Well-Grounded Rubyist by David A. Black (Jun 4, 2009)`](http://www.amazon.com/David-A.-Black/e/B001K7RPQO) is awesome book to learn.